# How can I track the value of options live in my portfolio

Tags: options, portfolio, option-exercise

With stocks I can enter price and amount into most applications and they allow me track the total Profit / Loss live.

Are there any ways to do this with option positions?

I was considering entering the price + premium and number of shares but that would only count if I exercise the options?

Are there any (free) applications or services that will track that and show me a total Profit / Loss value? Especially for the iPhone?

Comment: On which index are the options being traded?

Comment: most likely your brokerage firm has a way to do it. What firm are you using?

Comment: I'm using TD Waterhouse and they kind of do this - though I was looking more for an iphone or web application that I can just check daily without logging into my banking site every time.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume that you have an online brokerage account which has tools for you to use and will show you your current profit/loss. Additionally, popular brokerage firms have apps which should at a minimum show the the profit/loss on your positions.